# How to customize Yii CGridView Pager?

Tags: php, yii

How to customize Yii CGridView Pager about its position, css, template?

Answer (score 15):

You can custumize via 'pager' CGridView properties. Example:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'My-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'pager'=>array(
        'header'         => '',
        'firstPageLabel' => '&lt;&lt;',
        'prevPageLabel'  => '<img src="images/pagination/left.png">',
        'nextPageLabel'  => '<img src="images/pagination/right.png">',
        'lastPageLabel'  => '&gt;&gt;',
    ),
    'template'=>'{pager}{items}{pager}',
    'columns'=>$arrayColumns,
));
```

Answer (score 5):

1. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CBaseListView#pager-detail
2. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CBaseListView#pagerCssClass-detail
3. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CLinkPager

Comment: If you want just to customize how it looks you can use http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CLinkPager#cssFile-detail to apply your own styles.

These properties are specified in the array http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CBaseListView#pager-detail. So property name is key, property value is value.

If you want to customize markup itself or generation login it's better to create your own component that extends CLinkPager or CBasePager and specify its class as value of "class" key of CBaseListView::pager property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach which worked for me.

[Displaying Yii's CLinkPager "First" and "Last" Buttons](http://www.benjaminlhaas.com/blog/displaying-yiis-clinkpager-first-and-last-buttons)

If you have troubles, make sure to read the comments below the entry.

Comment: Please post the link's answer in your answer in case that link ever dies.