# How to change GridView column size in YII?

Tags: php, gridview, yii, width

Im trying change my GridView column width. This is my code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'prefixs-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'header' => 'No.',
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'center'),
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'pfx',
            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => 30),
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

When i run 'pfx' columns width must be changed to 30, but width is same. How i can change width of column? Any ideas?

Comment: php `'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'width30'),`
css `.width30 { width: 30px; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902723/how-to-customize-yii-cgridview-pager

Comment: I used class but not helped...

Comment: i think filters input not changes size. when i delete filter it works... but i must use a filter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not want to use a separated CSS definition you should do:

```
'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 30px;'),
'filterHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 30px;'),
```

Comment: i used this too. but filters input not changed.

Comment: `htmlOptions` don't get applied to GridView's header and filters rows, so this won't work if you're trying to make the column narrower than the content of either of them.

Comment: CDataColumn also has a filterHtmlOptions property. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
'columns' => [      
    [
         'headerOptions' => ['width' => '150'],
         'attribute' => 'name',
         'format' => 'raw',
          'value' => 'name'
    ],
]
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers! It is preferable to also shortly explain what the code does or why it works.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to approach this issue.

You can widen the cell's contents (cells of individual rows):

```
$columns[] = array(
    'header'=>'Name',
    'value'=>'$data["name"]',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 150px')
);
```

Sometimes you may want to widen the column header instead of the individual rows' cells:

```
$columns[] = array(
    'header'=>'Name',
    'value'=>'$data["name"]',
    'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width: 150px')
);
```

Widening the header is the preferred option, but even if you do that, sometimes it doesn't work as expected.

If this is the case, you can go my personal preferred way and widen the **contents** of the header cell. The widening will be inherited by the rows below it as well.

```
$columns[] = array(
    'header'=>'<div style="width:150px;">Name</div>',
    'value'=>'$data["name"]',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i noticed with cgridview in the  tags there is an id attribute `id="table-name_c0" id="table-name_c1"` etc. you could hook into this and the `.filters` class for the filter width. e.g.

```
#table-name table-name_c0 {
    width: 30px;
}

#table-name .filters:nth(0) {
    width:30px;
}
```

where c0 and :nth(0) are the same number.
it's slightly hacky but what you are trying to achieve is also slightly hacky imho

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

`'contentOptions' =>['style' => 'width:30px'],`

-- For example:

```
'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'product.name',
            'contentOptions' =>['style' => 'width:30px'],
        ],
```

That should do the trick!