# How to display Yii's CLinkPager first and last buttons

Tags: php, yii

My page number is like:

```
Page:1 2 3 4 5 last
```

But I want to change it like:

```
<< first | < previous | 1 | ... | 5 | next > | last >>
```

How to change this?

My code is:

```
<?php
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'currentPage' => $pages->getCurrentPage(),
    'itemCount' => $item_count,
    'pageSize' => $page_size,
    //'linkHash'=>'ls',
    'maxButtonCount' => 5,
    'firstPageLabel' => '',
    'prevPageLabel' => '',
    'nextPageLabel' => '',
    'lastPageLabel' => 'last',
    'header' => '<p>Page:</p>',
    /*'pager'=>array(
    'class'=>'MyLinkPager',
    'linkHash'=>'test'
    ),*/

    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'pages'
    )
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
   $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
      'currentPage' => $pages->getCurrentPage(),
      'itemCount' => $item_count,
      'pageSize' => $page_size,
      //'linkHash'=>'ls',
     'maxButtonCount' => 5,
     'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active',
     'hiddenPageCssClass'=>'disabled',
     'firstPageCssClass'=>'previous',
     'firstPageLabel' => '<< first | ',
     'prevPageLabel' => 'previous |',
     'nextPageLabel' => ' | next',
     'lastPageLabel' => ' | last >>',
     'header' => '<p>Page:</p>',
     /*'pager'=>array(
       'class'=>'MyLinkPager',
'      linkHash'=>'test'
     ),*/

  'htmlOptions' => array(
    'class' => 'pages'
  )
)); ?>
```

Comment: Now it displays Page:1 2 3 4 5 | last »». The same problem will occur the first page label will not shown

Comment: Respect to mine pager i also use CssClass but i use `<` char. I have update the answer with my working value.

Comment: Now it displays as Page:1 2 3 4 5 | last >> . How can i rectify this help me to fix this

Comment: I'm trying. Try changing the content of the field 'firstPageLabe'l eg by only' firts' no other characters to figure out if it is a problem related to the content or if it is linked to the layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88373/discussion-between-gautham-m-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to set a page labels.
You can use this instead of yout current definition:

```
'firstPageLabel' => '&laquo;&laquo; first',
'prevPageLabel' => '&laquo; previus',
'nextPageLabel'=>'next &raquo;',
'lastPageLabel'=>'last &raquo;&raquo;',
'maxButtonCount' => 5
```

To style a vertical separator you can use a css:

```
'cssFile' => Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/css/your_pager_css.css',
```

Place new css file to css dir and define a needed styles of a pager.

Some ideas: http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/pagination/basicPager

[How to customize Yii CGridView Pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902723/how-to-customize-yii-cgridview-pager)