# Yii Clinkpager displays next 3 buttons and last 3

Tags: php, yii

guys!
I need some help. I need display pagination in the following view:
1 2 3 ... 98 99 100.
How can I do that in Clinkpager?
I have tried override method createButtons, but really I don't know what conditions :

```
   for($i=$beginPage;$i<=$endPage;++$i){

            if($this->maxButtonCount < $pageCount){

                $next = $currentPage + 3;
                if($currentPage <= $next || $currentPage >= $pageCount-3){
                    $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($i+1,$i,$this->internalPageCssClass,false,$i==$currentPage);
                }
            }else{
                $buttons[]=$this->createPageButton($i+1,$i,$this->internalPageCssClass,false,$i==$currentPage);
            }



    }
```

But it not work.

Comment: I think this might be helpful for your case:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32310152/2260582

Comment: I have read this post thank, but there no solution